# How do i enabled a Google Maps button in a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

In a custom tableViewCell , I connect a View which is a google map class to the custom class

However it seems that these line of code doesn't run in the custom cell that I created

This cell is part of a tableView, I tried to instantiate this cell for example `var gmapsCell = GMapTableViewCell` in the viewDidLoad of the TableView but it seems it will always returns nil

So I change my approach to below codes

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class GMapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, GMSMapViewDelegate  {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // For use in foreground
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}


extension GMapTableViewCell: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }
}
```

The problem right now is that

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // For use in foreground
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    }
```

This will never run. My goal is simply to get to the device's current location. Are there any equivalent of viewDidLoad for custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" key as a string type in info.plist for the location Manager to start updating locations.[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that code inside awakeNib() should be written in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath. 
Set all the delegates there.
It will work fine then.